# inability to send mail through sendmail method using SMTP object using python

Tags: python, linux, email, smtp

I am trying to test email notifications using Python and found an example code at [code4reference.com](http://code4reference.com/2013/07/simple-python-script-to-send-an-email/). Upon running the sample code, I encounter the following error

```
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Is there some utility that needs to be installed in my Linux box to allow it to send emails or am i missing something else?

Comment: There seems to be multiple Q&A on this exact error in this site. Maybe you can try google first. If the situation is different with others, we will need more information (eg, your code), to help you.

Comment: the problem is printed out to you - script could not connect to to remote server. Check first connection to the server using `telnet hostname port`, if they would be ok, use your script with correctly passed hostname and port to the class constructor

Comment: If you're trying to send to localhost, then yes, of course you need a local server. If you're trying to send to, say, gmail, then most likely either the remote host is refusing you because you "look spammy" or a firewall on your side is blocking you (e.g., GoDaddy forces hosted servers to use their SMTP relays and won't let you talk directly to an outside SMTP). If it's some arbitrary host you just picked at random, it also may just not have a mail server.

Comment: At any rate, without a lot more information (see Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example in the Help), nobody can give you an answer, just vague general hints that may not be relevant to you at all.